# How to solve the problems caused by WSL 2's filesystem changes?

Tags: windows, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, intellij-idea, wsl2

Ever since I upgraded to WSL 2 the builds of my projects (that I have on a local NTFS drive) are **horribly slow**. For example if I build a project from windows, I get 20-30s build times, the same from WSL2 is around 3 minutes.

Another problem is that the file watch functionality doesn't work at all, so I can't use programs that would listen to changes on my filesystem.

I was told that a solution for this is to simply move my projects into a WSL-managed filesystem. This is a good idea, but then I can't open my projects from my IDE of choice (IntelliJ IDEA).

Is there a trivial solution for this problem? Can I access files stored in a WSL 2 filesystem from a regular IDE somehow?

Answer (score 7):

Same issue(s) as a fullstack dev I routinely find myself needing to run a build process in WSL2 and change files in Windows (i.e. SVG files in Affinity publisher, inkscape, etc.).

Move your project(s) folder into the WSL2 filesystem (ext4 or whatever), this way you get posix permissions, inotify 'monitor' filesystem hooks work, etc.  and performance is much faster.

THEN TO ACCESS the Linux WSL2 filesystem in Windows Explorer (i.e. via any Windows App) Use path \\wsl$\

TIP: spend the 3 seconds to create a shortcut in your default documents, downloads, etc. directories that points directly to your \wsl$\projects\folder

Comment: An easy way to open a folder on WSL2 from windows is to go into the folder, in your distro bash, and type: `explorer.exe .` , hope it helps

Comment: I had a case of some plugin not able to handle paths starting with `\\ ..` To tackle this I made a symlink somewhere in my normal windows folder and pointed that to the `\\wsl .. ` path. This way you can access it again as if it were a normal windows directory.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions, WSL1 outperforms WSL2 w.r.t. "performance across OS file systems". One solution, provided you don't rely on other WSL2-specific features, is to set your image's WSL version to 1 by using `wsl --set-version <distribution name> <versionNumber=1>`.

Regarding the "regular IDE access to WSL2 file system" aspect, I can't tell for IntelliJ but Visual Studio Code offers a neat integration with WSL2 images (i.e. running native on Windows while offering file system and bash access for Linux). See for example https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl-tutorial or https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode.

Comment: I use phpstorm which is the IntelliJ IDE for php and, it can access the wsl filesystem normally, when you open a project and you have a WSL2 distro active you'll be able to see its directory at the end of the directories list as `\\wsl$\distro_name`, where `distro_name` is the name of the currently active WSL distro.

But, it worth to mention that the IDE I/O performance is much slower when working on projects from the WSL filesystem, it's a trade-off you'll have to make but, having a little bit slow IDE is much better than a horribly slow server app.